# interval keeps firing even though clearInterval has been called

Tags: javascript, for-loop, setinterval, infinite-loop

I am trying to get a function to run 10 times with a pause inbetween each run, yet when I try to it repeats the function infinite times then after 10 times it pauses, and so on. Right now this is the code with the problem:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++) {
    console.log(i);
    interval = setInterval(function() {console.log("Function ran");}, 1000);
}
window.clearInterval(interval);
```

**Console:**
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
Function ran
**["Function ran" is repeated infinite times after "9"]**

Comment: setInterval doesn't block!

Comment: You've just created 10 intervals, and overwritten the `interval` variable each time, so the only one of those 10 intervals you have a reference to and can stop, is the last one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
interval = setInterval(function() {console.log("Function ran");}, 1000);
```

This line creates a new interval-instance each time, which means you have created 10 intervals. At the end of the loop `interval` holds the id of the last interval that was created. Hence that's the only one you're clearing, and the other ones are still running.

To cancel the interval, you need to keep track of how many times the function has been invoked. One way you can do that is as follows:

```
function pauseAndRepeat(delay, iterations, func) {
    var i = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        func();
        if(++i === iterations) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, delay);    
}
```

Here we have a function that defines a counter (`i`) in its local scope. Then it creates an interval using a function that checks the counter to see if it should call your function (`func`) or clear the interval when it is done. `interval` will have been set when the interval-handler is actually called. In this case the handler is basically a closure since it is bound to the local scope of `pauseAndRepeat`.

Then you can invoke the function as follows:

```
pauseAndRepeat(1000, 10, function() {
    console.log("Function ran");
});
```

This will print out `Function ran` ten times, pausing for a second each time.

Answer (score 1):

`setInterval` is expected to run forever, on an interval. Every time you call `setInterval` here, you have a new infinite loop running your function every 10s, and as others have noted you only are canceling the last one.

You may do better with chained `setTimeout` calls:

```
var counter = 0;

function next() {
    if (counter < 10) {
        counter++;
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("Function ran");
            next();
        }, 1000);
    }
}

next();
```

This chains delayed functions, setting a timeout for the next one after each runs. You can do something similar with `setInterval` and cancellation:

```
var counter = 0;

var intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    console.log("Function ran");
    if (++counter >= 10) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    }
}, 1000);
```

In both these cases the key issue is that you trigger the next run or cancel the interval *within the callback function*, not in synchronous code.